# AS 2 to AS 3 confusion - Making buttons clickable <to url> for only a certain number of frames

Tags: actionscript-3

I belive i have searched through SO thoroughly and still haven't found what I am looking for, so its time for a question. I dont use flash much anymore but as small part of one of my freelance jobs I use it four times a year to make a small movie inserted into a wordpress site for adverts. Previously I just recycled Action Script 2 stuff that I understood sort-of but, after upgrading to CC, I am very lost and cannot get this simple lil thing to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The gist of it is this -

I have an area 120 x 600 with four buttons in it that change every 40 frames. I just want to attach an action to each button, while they are visible, to be able to be clicked and lead to an url _blank. Previously I could target the button in the actions panel but I cannot seem to do that anymore. I have done all the more obvious stuff ( to me ) - making sure they have instance names, exporting for as, ect. I have tried as like the follwing only with my instance names

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goThere);
function goThere(e:MouseEvent){
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.foundation-flash.com/");
    navigateToURL(request);
```

and nothing works.

I get this error often but cannot figure out how to fix it

1046: type was not found or was not a complie-time constant

forgive me if I am missing something obvious or an answer here on SO. I have really been searching and trying to solve this.

If anyone could help that would be great!!!

Thanks!!!

Josh

Comment: Is that the whole error message you are getting? It doesn't say more?

Comment: No just that in terms of messaging.
in conjunction with it not working at all as a clickable link.
I had a small bit of luck with making it a MC but that only will work for the first part of the movie ie the first 40 frames. Then its a total mess <-- best way to describe it. :)

Comment: Are you sure you don't forget } or you just dont paste all code?
1046 is typical error then you define classes, but here...

Comment: try debug movie (ctrl+shift+Enter) instead of run movie (ctrl+Enter), you should have better error message and the line corresponding to the error